# Creating a Transparent Blurry effect using css or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using bxSlider and I have a small form placed on top of slider (say 40% of width of slider and of same height) using position: absolute.
Now, the background of form needs to be tranparent (which is acheived using png image), but it should also **BLUR** the portion of slider image that comes behind the form part.

I tried Blur.js but it seems to work only with background images. I am also unable to create any such images, that blurs any other image coming behind that image.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Set a CSS filter to blur the background. Add it with JS when your form is visible over the slider image

```
/*change 5px with your favorite value. Test it*/
.blur{
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: depending of your html, you can also add this css property directly with the css selectors. Ex: `.form + .slider {
   filter...
}`

Comment: blur filter definitely makes my background blur, but image behind that still remains same.
Also on increasing blur value, the edges are lost :(

But Thanks :)

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of your solution ?